# Is there a way to get the name of an app that was just removed?

Tags: android

I am able to get the package name of apps that were removed by setting up a receiver to listen for android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED intents. To get the name of the app from there, I usually ask the PackageManager for the app name corresponding to that package name. However, because i get notified that a package was removed *after* it was removed, I can't get the app name from the PackageManager since it is no longer installed.

Is there any way for me to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you may need to keep a local copy of all of the app names. Register your receiver with:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
    <data android:scheme="package"/> 
</intent-filter>
```

to keep tabs on everything (including changing names on REPLACED).

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing. I don't see a way to get the app name from there though.

Comment: Well if you have a local list of names and package names before they are uninstalled, you can simply query for the package and retrieve the corresponding name from your local list, before removing it. Follow me?

Comment: Yeah I see what you're saying, I was hoping to be able to do this without storing the names of every app though.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Comment: Interesting suggestion, that is a possible solution but in my current situation I don't want to have to query the market in order to get the app name.